# Construction events: Get the condition from the previous inspection

Tags: oracle, select, oracle-12c, date

[image]

I have a `constr_events` table:

```
create table constr_events
   (    
    event_id number(4) not null unique,
    road_id number(4) not null,
    constr_date date not null,
    reset_condition number(9,2) not null
   ) ;
insert into constr_events (event_id, road_id, constr_date, reset_condition) values (1,400,to_date('2016-11-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),1);
insert into constr_events (event_id, road_id, constr_date, reset_condition) values (2,500,to_date('2009-11-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),1);
insert into constr_events (event_id, road_id, constr_date, reset_condition) values (3,500,to_date('2031-11-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),1);
select
    event_id,
    road_id,
    to_char(constr_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') as constr_date_formatted,
    reset_condition
from
    constr_events
order by
    road_id,
    constr_date;

  EVENT_ID    ROAD_ID CONSTR_DATE_FORMATTED  RESET_CONDITION
---------- ---------- ---------------------  ---------------
         1        400 2016-11-01                           1

         2        500 2009-11-01                           1
         3        500 2031-11-01                           1
```

---

And a `road_insp` table:

```
create table road_insp
   (    
    insp_id number(4) not null unique,
    road_id number(4) not null,
    insp_date date not null, 
    condition number(9,2) not null
   ) ;
insert into road_insp (insp_id, road_id, insp_date, condition) values (40,400,to_date('1960-05-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),.8);
insert into road_insp (insp_id, road_id, insp_date, condition) values (41,400,to_date('2009-05-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),.3);
insert into road_insp (insp_id, road_id, insp_date, condition) values (42,400,to_date('2012-05-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),.3);
insert into road_insp (insp_id, road_id, insp_date, condition) values (43,400,to_date('2015-05-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),.2);
insert into road_insp (insp_id, road_id, insp_date, condition) values (45,400,to_date('2019-05-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),.9);

--insert into road_insp (insp_id, road_id, insp_date, condition) values (50,500,to_date('1994-05-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),.6);
--insert into road_insp (insp_id, road_id, insp_date, condition) values (90,500,to_date('2006-05-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),.30);
insert into road_insp (insp_id, road_id, insp_date, condition) values (67,500,to_date('2010-05-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),.9);
insert into road_insp (insp_id, road_id, insp_date, condition) values (68,500,to_date('2014-05-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),.9);
insert into road_insp (insp_id, road_id, insp_date, condition) values (69,500,to_date('2017-05-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),.9);
insert into road_insp (insp_id, road_id, insp_date, condition) values (70,500,to_date('2020-05-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),.8);
insert into road_insp (insp_id, road_id, insp_date, condition) values (71,500,to_date('2023-05-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),.8);
insert into road_insp (insp_id, road_id, insp_date, condition) values (72,500,to_date('2026-05-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),.7);
insert into road_insp (insp_id, road_id, insp_date, condition) values (73,500,to_date('2029-05-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),.6);
insert into road_insp (insp_id, road_id, insp_date, condition) values (74,500,to_date('2032-05-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),.9);
insert into road_insp (insp_id, road_id, insp_date, condition) values (75,500,to_date('2035-05-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),.9);
commit;
select
    insp_id,
    road_id,
    to_char(insp_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') as insp_date_formatted,
    condition as condition
from
    road_insp
order by
    road_id,
    insp_date;

   INSP_ID    ROAD_ID INSP_DATE_FORMATTED  CONDITION
---------- ---------- ------------------- ----------
        40        400 1960-05-01                  .8
        41        400 2009-05-01                  .3
        42        400 2012-05-01                  .3
        43        400 2015-05-01                  .2  --last inspection before construction
        45        400 2019-05-01                  .9

        67        500 2010-05-01                  .9
        68        500 2014-05-01                  .9
        69        500 2017-05-01                  .9
        70        500 2020-05-01                  .8
        71        500 2023-05-01                  .8
        72        500 2026-05-01                  .7
        73        500 2029-05-01                  .6  --last inspection before construction
        74        500 2032-05-01                  .9
        75        500 2035-05-01                  .9
```

---

When I union the tables together, they look like this:

```
select
    road_id,
    to_char(insp_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') as condition_date,
    condition as condition,
    'INSPECTION' as type
from
    road_insp
union all
select
    road_id,
    to_char(constr_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') as condition_date,
    reset_condition,
    'CONSTRUCTION' as type
from
    constr_events
order by
    road_id,
    condition_date

   ROAD_ID CONDITION_DATE  CONDITION TYPE        
---------- -------------- ---------- ------------
       400 1960-05-01             .8 INSPECTION  
       400 2009-05-01             .3 INSPECTION  
       400 2012-05-01             .3 INSPECTION  
       400 2015-05-01             .2 INSPECTION  
       400 2016-11-01              1 CONSTRUCTION
       400 2019-05-01             .9 INSPECTION  

       500 2009-11-01              1 CONSTRUCTION
       500 2010-05-01             .9 INSPECTION  
       500 2014-05-01             .9 INSPECTION  
       500 2017-05-01             .9 INSPECTION  
       500 2020-05-01             .8 INSPECTION  
       500 2023-05-01             .8 INSPECTION  
       500 2026-05-01             .7 INSPECTION  
       500 2029-05-01             .6 INSPECTION  
       500 2031-11-01              1 CONSTRUCTION
       500 2032-05-01             .9 INSPECTION  
       500 2035-05-01             .9 INSPECTION
```

---

For each **construction event**, I want to generate a dummy **road inspection** that gets the condition from the previous inspection.

The dummy inspection would have these attributes:

- `road_id` from the the **construction** event
- `condition_date` from the **construction** event, but it would be January 1st of that year
- `condition` from the previous road **inspection**
- `type` as *"CARRYOVER FROM PREVIOUS INSPECTION"*

It would look like this:

```
   ROAD_ID CONDITION_DATE  CONDITION TYPE        
---------- -------------- ---------- ------------
       400 1960-05-01             .8 INSPECTION  
       400 2009-05-01             .3 INSPECTION  
       400 2012-05-01             .3 INSPECTION  
       400 2015-05-01             .2 INSPECTION  
       400 2016-01-01             .2 CARRYOVER FROM PREVIOUS INSPECTION
       400 2016-11-01              1 CONSTRUCTION
       400 2019-05-01             .9 INSPECTION  

       500 2009-11-01              1 CONSTRUCTION
       500 2010-05-01             .9 INSPECTION  
       500 2014-05-01             .9 INSPECTION  
       500 2017-05-01             .9 INSPECTION  
       500 2020-05-01             .8 INSPECTION  
       500 2023-05-01             .8 INSPECTION  
       500 2026-05-01             .7 INSPECTION  
       500 2029-05-01             .6 INSPECTION  
       500 2031-01-01             .6 CARRYOVER FROM PREVIOUS INSPECTION
       500 2031-11-01              1 CONSTRUCTION
       500 2032-05-01             .9 INSPECTION  
       500 2035-05-01             .9 INSPECTION
```

---

How can I create a query that generates the dummy construction events?

**Update:**

I've come across situations where a road's first record is a `constr_event`, not an `insp_event`. I've updated the DDL to reflect this scenario (deleted inspections `#50` and `#90`).

When this is the case, **@Joe Obbish's** query returns null values for the `condition`. Preferably, instead of returning a record with a null, the queries would simply not return a record at all.

Is there an elegant way to force the query to do this, or is the only solution to wrap the query in a subselect and use a where clause (`where condition is not null`)?

Comment: Are you able to add indexes to the tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fill in the missing rows you need exactly one row per row in the `constr_events` table. It's straightforward to get these three columns just by querying that table:

> road_id from the the construction event
>
> condition_date from the construction event, but it would be January
>   1st of that year
>
> type as "CARRYOVER FROM PREVIOUS INSPECTION"

That leaves just this one:

> condition from the previous road inspection

A correlated subquery can be a good option when you need to pull exactly one column value from another table. You're on Oracle 12c, so you can take advantage of the expanded `ORDER BY` syntax. Here's one way to get the results that you want:

```
SELECT
    road_id,
    TO_DATE('01-01-' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM constr_date), 'dd-mm-yyyy') condition_date,
    (
        SELECT condition
        FROM road_insp ri
        WHERE ri.road_id = constr_events.road_id
        AND ri.insp_date < constr_events.constr_date
        ORDER BY insp_date DESC FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
    ) AS condition,
    'CARRYOVER FROM PREVIOUS INSPECTION' AS TYPE
FROM
    constr_events
```

Depending on the size of your tables you may want an index on the `road_id` and `insp_date` columns of the `road_insp` table. Consider what would happen if the query optimizer implemented the subquery with a nested loop join and there was no index. You would do a full scan of the `road_insp` table for each row in `constr_events`. An index as described earlier allows Oracle to jump to the relevant `road_id` and to find the relevant `insp_date` without scanning all of the `insp_date` values. I would expect it to just be a handful of logical reads for each row in `constr_events`.

If you need to exclude rows with a NULL carryover you can do this by changing the subquery to use `CROSS APPLY`, `LATERAL JOIN`, or by wrapping the whole thing in a derived table and filtering on that column outside of the derived table.

Comment: In hindsight, I guess I should have named all the fields just as `date`, and not have three different names for the date fields (`insp_date`, `constr_date` and `condition_date`). It would have made things simpler for people to interpret. Sorry for the confusion. Is it wise to name fields just as `date`? Since date is an Oracle keyword, and it wouldn't be obvious which table it belongs to?

Comment: Thanks for the update about excluding nulls. I hadn't noticed this until now (didn't get an alert from SE).

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a CTE that unions the two tables together (`road_insp_constr_union`).
2. Use the lag function to isolate the inspection that comes previous to the construction event.
3. Union the result with the CTE.

---

```
with road_insp_constr_union as (
        select
            road_id,
            insp_date as condition_date,
            condition as condition,
            'INSPECTION' as type
        from
            road_insp
        union all
        select
            road_id,
            constr_date as condition_date,
            reset_condition,
            'CONSTRUCTION' as type
        from
            constr_events
)
select
    road_id,
    to_date('01-01-' || extract(year from condition_date), 'dd-mm-yyyy') condition_date,
    prev_condition as condition,
    'CARRYOVER FROM PREVIOUS INSPECTION' as type
from
    (
    select
        road_id,
        condition_date,
        condition,
        type,
        lag ( condition ) over ( partition by road_id order by road_id, condition_date ) prev_condition
    from
        road_insp_constr_union
    )
where 
    type = 'CONSTRUCTION'
    and prev_condition is not null
union all
select
    road_id,
    condition_date,
    condition,
    type
from
    road_insp_constr_union
order by
    road_id,
    condition_date;

   ROAD_ID CONDITION  CONDITION TYPE                              
---------- --------- ---------- ----------------------------------
       400 01-MAY-60         .8 INSPECTION                        
       400 01-MAY-09         .3 INSPECTION                        
       400 01-MAY-12         .3 INSPECTION                        
       400 01-MAY-15         .2 INSPECTION                        
       400 01-JAN-16         .2 CARRYOVER FROM PREVIOUS INSPECTION
       400 01-NOV-16          1 CONSTRUCTION                      
       400 01-MAY-19         .9 INSPECTION                        

       500 01-NOV-09          1 CONSTRUCTION                      
       500 01-MAY-10         .9 INSPECTION                        
       500 01-MAY-14         .9 INSPECTION                        
       500 01-MAY-17         .9 INSPECTION                        
       500 01-MAY-20         .8 INSPECTION                        
       500 01-MAY-23         .8 INSPECTION                        
       500 01-MAY-26         .7 INSPECTION                        
       500 01-MAY-29         .6 INSPECTION                        
       500 01-JAN-31         .6 CARRYOVER FROM PREVIOUS INSPECTION
       500 01-NOV-31          1 CONSTRUCTION                      
       500 01-MAY-32         .9 INSPECTION                        
       500 01-MAY-35         .9 INSPECTION
```

---

[image]